# How can I use the table function with a collection of inputs of length two?

Tags: r

Suppose that I have some collection of data where each entry is of length two. For example, `replicate(10,sample(5,2,replace = T))`. I want to feed this in to the `table` function, so that I can see how often each pair (e.g. (3,5)) occurs. Can this be done? The obvious solution of `table(replicate(10,sample(5,2,replace = T)))` acts as if I've given it 20 length one inputs rather than 10 length two inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need the pairwise `count`, convert to `data.frame` and use `count`

```
library(dplyr)
t(replicate(10,sample(5,2,replace = T))) %>% 
    as.data.frame %>% 
    count(V1, V2)
```

---

Or `paste` the elements and apply `table`

```
table(sapply(replicate(10,sample(5,2,replace = TRUE), 
      simplify = FALSE), paste, collapse = ' '))
```

---

Or if we need the output in a `matrix`, then after converting to `data.frame` apply the `table`.  (The output of `replicate` by default is an `array` -as it uses `simplify = TRUE` by default.  The `matrix` is a `vector` `dim` attributes)

```
table(as.data.frame(t(replicate(10,sample(5,2,replace = T)))))
```